# Kubernetes - Running 2 services with ingress

Tags: express, kubernetes-ingress

Scenario:
I would like to have 2 services in one cluster. ServiceA and ServiceB. ServiceA should then receive a request and then call ServiceB directly.

Unfortunately, this does not work and I cannot explain why.
Maybe someone can help me.
I don't think anything arrives at my pods :)

Express - ServiceA

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    
    res.send('Service A:')
    let dataInfo="112"

    await axios.get('http://serviceb-srv:8091/numbercheck', {
        type: 'InfoCheck',
        data: {
            dataInfo
        }
    })

    res.status(201).send("<h1>ServiceA</h1>");

});

app.listen(8090, () => {
    console.log('Server A läuft auf Port: 8090 :)')
})
```

Express - ServiceB

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/numbercheck', async (req,res) => {
    
    res.send('Service B get information ...')
    res.status(201).send("ok");
});

app.listen(8091, () => {
    console.log('Server B läuft auf Port: 8091 :)')
})
```

ingress-srv.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingressab-srv
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: hellowi.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /numbercheck
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: serviceb-srv
                port:
                  number: 8091
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: servicea-srv
                port:
                  number: 8090
```

servicea-depl.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: servicea-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: servicea
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: servicea
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: servicea
          image: mgsnow/servicea
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: servicea-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: servicea
  ports:
    - name: servicea
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8090
      targetPort: 8090
```

serviceb-depl.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serviceb-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: serviceb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: serviceb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: serviceb
          image: mgsnow/serviceb
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serviceb-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: serviceb
  ports:
    - name: serviceb
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8091
      targetPort: 8091
```